# What does this suffix mean in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

What does the suffix mean in this function?

```
glGetActiveUniformsiv​
```

I believe it means an array of integers, but I may be wrong, and I don't know what it stands for, like what the 'v' could mean. Values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GLSL an array passed by glGetActiveUniformsiv​ is called a Vector (as in vec3, vec4) in the GLSL code.

Comment: That's not what the `v` means though (vector in the sense of the GLSL vector types). See the answers by jbro and stonemetal for correct explanations.

Answer (score 4):

http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0630&db=bks&srch=&fname=/SGI_Developer/OpenGL_Porting/sgi_html/apc.html

i is integer

V is vector (pointer to an array of values)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The "iv" indicates that the function returns a vector of ints. If you look at the OpenGL documentation you see that the argument *params* has type GLint*, so this is a pointer to memory that will receive the requested uniform values.